# What's the proper way to setup a domain name to not accept email?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, domain, mx-record

[RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) sec. 5 states that:

1. SMTP clients must look up for an MX record;
2. if no MX record for domain is present, look up for an A Resource Record (RR), and if such record is present, treat it as an MX record;
3. if an MX record is present, clients MUST NOT use an A RR.

So what if I want to set a domain with SSH access only and explicitly no emails are accepted?

Currently I had it set up with an A record to its IP address, and MX set to `invalid.`.

Since if I don't set up a MX record, then a client may resolve to the A record and connecting to it there.

But if I set up a MX record with an invalid domain, such as `invalid.`, then the client will not use the A record, and the MX record does not get resolved to anything, so it doesn't affect other servers out there.

Is there a proper way to do this?

**This isn't a question of OMGZ spambots are coming what do I need to do.** However 'nothing' is a perfectly good answer provided there are actually no specification of DNS that allows you to explicitly say 'there are no email configured for this domain'.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: ... Don't set up/open the port for a mail server?

Comment: If you're not running an email server then other email servers aren't going to connect to anything, so the answer is don't do anything. If you don't run an email server for the domain then don't create an MX record. You're not required to do anything... so don't.

Comment: Ports are already closed, they are closed by default. I guess a spammer/bot will attempt to connect to the A record as it resolves to it, but for everything else it would be nice if it does not make a connection to begin with.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes I understand it is not required, this is more of a curiosity/perfectionist/purist question - what is /supposed/ to be in the DNS for cases like this.

Comment: Again, don't do anything. That is the answer. This isn't something network/system administrators worry about. If there's no email they don't worry about whether or not some random email server or spambot will try to connect to their A record via SMTP.

Comment: Well, as long as there are no email accounts being created, no harm will be done and the spammers can't do anything. You can:

1) Ensure that the mail service is stopped/disabled
2) Ensure that the common mail ports (25, 26, 587 etc.) are closed
3) Perhaps set an 'A' record for mail.domain.com and point the MX of it to 127.0.0.1 to confuse the 'spambots'

Comment: @joeqwerty again, this is more of a curiosity/perfectionist/purist question. I am not worrying about it.

Comment: @Machoke - I get that. The answer is you don't do anything.

Comment: @joeqwerty I get that you don't need to do anything - the question wasn't "spambot coming in what needs to be done".

Answer (score 2):

**Do not set up an MX** record if you don't want to receive mails.

Also **do not open the SMTP port** (25).

Some spambots surely will try to send an email to your domani but they will be rejected as there won't be any service to accept them.

If you have to operate a mail server anyway **set up the mail server to REJECT emails coming to that domain**.

Comment: Ports are already closed, they are closed by default. This question were asked to see if that's a standard for specifying no mail server, as there is a standard to fallback to the A record if no MX are configured. If there are no such thing and the de facto standard is simply not setting up a MX record, then I think this is a perfectly good answer.